# React Navigation transparent bar missing title and buttons on android

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

I'm building a `React Native` app with `React Navigation 2.5.x`. I have a transparent navigation bar. On iOS everything is fine, but on Android the title, back button and any barButton I put there is missing.

The navigation options is defined like this:

```
const navigationOptions = {
    headerStyle: {
        borderBottomWidth: 0,
    },
    headerTransparent: true,
    headerTintColor: Colors.barTintColor,
};
```

If I try to inspect the view I get the header component when tapping, but on Android I get the scenes content view instead.

Previously I had the header style positioned absolutely and a transparent background color. **I would like the bar to be transparent and visible above the rest of content screen.** But positioning it absolutely, setting headerMode och headerTransparent all makes the headers disappear.

What am I doing wrong?